# Installing Java EE 7 SDK on Debian 7.1.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, debian, java, glassfish-4

For all the day I'm trying to install Java EE SDK 7 on my computer in which it is installed Debian 7.1.0. My problem is that the process of installation start well but for an weird reason it remains stucked during the creation of the domain when it executes `asadmin` comand. I have installed java JDK 7 update 25. I have forwared correctly the port 8080 and 4848 in my router but I don't understand why the process doesn't proceed as well.

Here it is a screenshot:

[image]

The installation doesn't go ahead

Comment: You can also download the zip and unzip it.

Comment: I don't find any zip file in this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-downloads-1956236.html

Comment: @PaulVargas Please show me the link of the zip file

Comment: Maybe installation hangs because the ports (8080, 4848) aren't correctly opened. I forwarded them in my router but maybe debian has a firewall and it doesn't permit to listen

Comment: https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

Comment: @PaulVargas This zip file contains JAVE EE JDK 7?

Comment: I downloaded the zip file and tried to execute asadmin. Unfortunately I get this message: There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server. 
Command start-domain failed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any application using that port.

Comment: Ok now it works. I have to change the file /etc/hosts to set up the correct static ip

Answer (score 0):

Don't download the package from Oracle.  Try the ubuntu package like so.

```
$ echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

You may as well use the update-alternatives tool from java-common package which let you update all alternatives belonging to one runtime or development kit at a time.

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -l
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s j2sdk1.7-oracle
```

More info here
https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Now the installation goes ahead well. The problem was I have to set up correctly the `/etc/hosts` file since I'm using static ip.